# How can I know if /D parameter was passed into NSIS-based installer

Tags: parameters, installation, nsis

Is there any flag or other option in NSIS to see that the default $INSTDIR variable was changed via /D parameter passed to the installer?

I tried to do that:

```
1. setup.exe /D=C:\Temp
2. ${GetParameters} $R0
3. And see that $R0 is empty
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before `.onInit` is executed, `$InstDir` is set by `InstallDir`, then if the value defined by `InstallDirRegKey` exists it will override `InstallDir`. Finally, if the user used /D, `$InstDir` is set to that parameter. This is OK for most installers because you don't really need to know how `$InstDir` was set.

If you are using `RequestExecutionLevel highest` and your installer supports installing for a single user or all users depending on the elevation status then this is not OK. The only way around this is to not use `InstallDir*`

```
; DO NOT USE: InstallDir
; DO NOT USE: InstallDirRegKey

!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
${If} $InstDir != ""
  ; /D was used
${Else}
  ; Set some default
  StrCpy $InstDir "$ProgramFiles\foo\bar"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Alternatively you could maybe use `System::Call kernel32::GetCommandLine()t.r0` and parse $0 looking for /D at the end...

Comment: In my case I need to know how $InstDir was set, because my installer can change this path automatically at runtime, but if the path was set manually using /D, then it must stay as it was entered. System::Call actually did the trick and I can see that /D thing in the command line! Thanks a lot!